# Serving a page whose URL ends in a slash with nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, configuration

I want to make nginx serve an HTML file for `/foobar/`. I tried 2 configurations and neither worked.

In Apache you do it like this:

```
AliasMatch ^/foobar/$ /home/admin/foobar/foobar.html
```

My first attempt:

```
location /foobar/ {
    alias /home/admin/foobar/foobar.html;
}
```

Going to `/foobar/` shows a 500 error page. The error log says:

```
2011/08/05 04:12:35 [alert] 32465#0: *1 "/home/admin/foobar/foobar.htmlindex.html" is not a directory, ...
```

This is weird. Why did it append "index.html" to the end of the file path?

My next attempt:

```
location ~ ^/foobar$ {
    alias /home/admin/foobar/foobar.html;
}
```

Going to `/foobar` makes my browser download the file. This is weird. Why did that happen?

I was able to get it to work with this:

```
location /foobar.html {
    alias /home/admin/foobar/foobar.html;
}
```

This works, but it has the wrong URL. It has `/foobar.html` instead of `/foobar/`.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that the 'index.html' is appended is because of the [index](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpIndexModule) directive (probably in your main nginx.conf file)

It typically reads something similar to:

```
index index.php index.htm index.html
```

which tells nginx what to do when it is asked to serve a directory (in the above case, try to serve `index.php`, if that doesn't exist try `index.htm`, etc.)

What you can do, is to add an additional index directive within the location block if this is a special case, or if you always want to serve `foobar.html` for any directory, change your main index directive.

e.g. (to override the index for just one specific location):

```
location /foobar/ {
    index foobar.html;
}
```

Don't go putting an index directive in every location block if one outside the location blocks will do.